# MySQL query that returns all rows created before each month

Tags: mysql, date, count

I have a users table:

```
|id |created_at|
|---|----------|
|1  |2016-11-15|
|2  |2016-08-30|
|3  |2016-06-23|
|4  |2015-12-03|
```

I want to run a query that returns each month and how many rows have been created up until that month.
The query I have now is:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) AS `year`, MONTH(created_at) AS `month`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM users
GROUP BY `year`, `month`
ORDER BY `year` DESC, `month` DESC
```

which returns the following table:

```
|year|month|count|
|----|-----|-----|
|2016|11   |1    |
|2016|8    |1    |
|2016|6    |1    |
|2015|12   |1    |
```

The table I want looks like this:

```
|year|month|count|
|----|-----|-----|
|2016|11   |4    |
|2016|8    |3    |
|2016|6    |2    |
|2015|12   |1    |
```

Or even better:

```
|year|month|count|
|----|-----|-----|
|2016|11   |4    |
|2016|10   |3    |
|2016|9    |3    |
|2016|8    |3    |
|2016|7    |2    |
|2016|6    |2    |
|2016|5    |1    |
|2016|4    |1    |
|2016|3    |1    |
|2016|2    |1    |
|2016|1    |1    |
|2015|12   |1    |
|2015|11   |0    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SET @tot=0;
SELECT max(rank) AS `cm` ,ym,count(*) AS `ct` 
FROM (
SELECT concat_ws('',YEAR(created_at) ,LPAD( MONTH(created_at),2,'0') ) AS `ym` ,@tot:=@tot + 1 AS `rank` FROM users
ORDER BY ym DESC) as a
GROUP BY ym
```

Comment: "try..." - why?  If you put some explanation it will make this a much better answer.

Comment: I thought it works why explain. but is seems not to be that obvious. 

First make a collection of all records with a record counter (rank).ordered by Year & month

Then select from that collection the highest count for every year-Month pair.

Comment: This is great but could I add another condition to the question.
How would you solve this if the id column wasn't a primary key and could have duplicate values but I only want to count distinct entries?

Comment: @Ton Thank you for adding explanation - please put it into the *post* rather than just a comment.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. The above solution works regardless of (primary ) key fields. if it somehow doesn't please post the code+DB structure where it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to test this.

```
SELECT YEAR(Created) as Year, MONTH(Created) as Month,
      count(*) AS num_daily_interactions,
       (
          SELECT 
             COUNT(*)
          FROM users l2
          WHERE DATE(l2.created_at) <= l1.created_at
       ) as total_interactions_per_day

    FROM `users ` as l1

    GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)
    ORDER BY YEAR(created_at) DESC, MONTH(created_at) DESC;
```

Comment: That looks like it would work but I have sql set up to only allow aggregate columns for a group by. How would I aggregate that fourth column?